# Left join and get Total records on joined table

Tags: mysql

I am using following query:

```
SELECT `users`.`id` as id 
FROM (`users`) 
    LEFT JOIN `work_orders` 
        ON `users`.`id` = `work_orders`.`assigned_to` 
WHERE (work_orders.status = 'approved' 
        OR work_orders.status = 'scheduled' 
        OR work_orders.status = 'published') 
    AND work_orders.is_paid = 0 
ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

But with this query I am getting multiple records for each `users` if they have more than one `work_orders`. What should I do to only list `users` *once* which have more than one `work_orders`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a GROUP BY statement to filter by user's ids because this is everythin you are interested in.

```
SELECT `users`.`id` as id 
FROM (`users`) LEFT JOIN `work_orders` ON `users`.`id` = `work_orders`.`assigned_to` 
WHERE (work_orders.status = 'approved' 
  OR work_orders.status = 'scheduled' 
  OR work_orders.status = 'published') 
  AND work_orders.is_paid = 0 
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Hello, can you please explain me difference between using distinct as answered by mike and Group by

Comment: I used this one works as expected. I would like to know which one is better choice from other answers because they work aswell

Comment: If you use the group statement you should be able to count the number of entries per user as well (I think by using COUNT(*)), which could be a nice extension. Otherwhise the DISTINCT statement should work as well. I am not sure, which behaves better w.r.t. performance but do not expect major differences.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DISTINCT clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(users.id) as id FROM (`users`) LEFT JOIN `work_orders` ON `users`.`id` = `work_orders`.`assigned_to` WHERE (work_orders.status = 'approved' OR work_orders.status = 'scheduled' OR work_orders.status = 'published') AND work_orders.is_paid = 0 ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Can you please explain me difference between using Group by As answered by claas and distinct?

Comment: Well, the `GROUP BY` will allow you to run aggregate functions on each group.  However, since you're not doing that, a `DISTINCT` seemed like the better approach.  I think in this case, the two would be fairly similar in terms of execution plans but I'm not a mySQL expert so I can't say for sure.  I'd use whichever one you like best.

Answer (score 0):

Try using GROUP BY

```
SELECT `users`.`id` as id 
  FROM (`users`) 
  LEFT JOIN `work_orders` 
    ON `users`.`id` = `work_orders`.`assigned_to` 
 WHERE ( work_orders.status = 'approved' 
       OR work_orders.status = 'scheduled' 
       OR work_orders.status = 'published' ) 
   AND work_orders.is_paid = 0 
GROUP BY `users`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `users`.`id` as id 
  FROM (`users`) 
  WHERE exists ( select 1 from `work_orders` where work_orders.status 
                     in  ('approved' ,'scheduled' ,'published' ) 
                     AND work_orders.is_paid = 0 
                     and `work_orders`.`assigned_to` =`users`.`id` )
 ORDER BY `users`.`id` DESC 
 LIMIT 30
```

Comment: This one looks more complex will it work on all mysql versions?